# Exceção sqlite no windows 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, wpf, windows-8

Estou recebendo essa Exceção ao tentar abrir uma janela dentro de um programa que eu fiz, o programa foi feito no visual studio 2017, com sqlite 3, ele abre normal só da esse problema ao tentar abrir uma janela que contem comandos sqlite.

Estou tentando rodar ele no windows 8. A DLL System.Data.SQLite.dll esta indo corretamente dentro da pasta do programa, e o banco de dados em si (.db) esta em uma pasta no AppData...
No windows 10 foi tudo OK.

> Aplicativo: AASistemaIdealSulZerado.exe Versão do Framework:
>   v4.0.30319 Descrição: O processo foi terminado devido a uma exceção
>   sem tratamento. Informações da Exceção: System.DllNotFoundException em
>   System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
>   em System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized() em
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize() em
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String, Boolean) em
>   AASistemaIdealSulZerado.dbclass.Dbideal..ctor(System.String) em
>   AASistemaIdealSulZerado.Entregas.EntregaCadastra1..ctor() em
>   AASistemaIdealSulZerado.MainWindow.Ir_NovaEntrega(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean) em
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() em
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() em
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
>   em System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object) em
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean) em
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent) em
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object) em
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean) em
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) em
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>   em System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() em
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
>   em
>   System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
>   em System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr,
>   System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32,
>   System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32) em
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr,
>   MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) em
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) em MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) em
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) em
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) em
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) em
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) em
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   em
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef) em
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   em System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) em
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) em
>   AASistemaIdealSulZerado.App.Main()

Comment: Verificou se a System.Data.SQLite está marcada como "Copy Local"?

Comment: Verifique o tipo do SO se **x86** ou **x64** e utilize a versao da dll adequada.